# Why does Russia have so many nuclear weapons?

Tags: russian-federation, nuclear-weapons, international-relations, soviet-union

In the Cold War, Soviet Russia produced 55,000 nukes, and it made 30,000 warheads in 1991. [[Source]](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.2968/066004008#:%7E:text=Russia%20has%20released%20very%20little,end%20of%20the%20Cold%20War)

Russia became one of the nations to have the largest nuclear stockpile and it has a deteriorating relationship with the US (one example: 2020 cyberattack). [[Source]](https://www.businessinsider.com/9-countries-with-the-most-nuclear-weapons-2019-6)

Russia for some reason loves nuclear power (which I find not surprising). Although the U.S. and Russia are on a nuclear deal (New Start) which got extended recently, I don't think the New Start covers it all. We have seen what happened to the poor INF treaty.

(I'm Not Comparing the US to Russia or Russia to the US neither I am Contrasting them)

Comment: For the same reason as the USA.

Comment: And What does "For the same reason as the USA" Mean. Clarify Please.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I get what you mean

Comment: But answer not through comment

Comment: I think Martin was alluding to the fact that the US and Russia have similar-sized nuclear stockpiles.

Comment: The U.S. Didn't violate treaties like Russia has @MartinSchröder

Comment: But The US and Russia use them in different ways @Sneftel

Comment: The title and body of this question don't agree. "Why does Russia have so many nuclear weapons?" is a good, on-topic question. "Is Russia up to something?" is not. I'm really not sure what the point of paragraphs 2-4 is

Comment: I can edit it. @divibisan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going entirely speculative here.

I think this is because Russia doesn't have an alliance like NATO.

NATO is a huge threat to Russia. The only option for Russia to counter NATO has been to form an alliance with China. However, Russia has a trust deficit with China since the Soviet time. During the Soviet time, the distrust became evident in the form of the Sino-Soviet Split. During the present time, the distrust is most probably because of China's habit of reverse engineering Russian defense products.

However, after US-China Trade War, Russia found a renewed reason to come closer to China. It's about US sanctions and the decline of the Russian Ruble.

Therefore, if the Chinese Yuan can dominate or at least become a parallel trustable currency in the international ForEx market, I think, we would be able to see a Sino-Russian alliance against NATO in our lifetimes.

In that case, we **might** see the reduction of nuclear weapons, but I am not optimistic.

Comment: This all seems plausible, but [Russia doesn't seem to have significantly more nuclear weapons than the US](https://www.armscontrol.org/factsheets/Nuclearweaponswhohaswhat), particularly if you include the UK and France in the numbers

Comment: Tell Me where in the question it said russia has many more nukes than the US

Comment: ( I was talking too @divibisan)